# How to get real-time completion/suggestions in Linux terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh

I would like to have something similar to `everything` in windows (using `locate`): every time I press a key, the file list that matches the current inputs gets updated immediately.

I am wondering is that possible to do real-time text completion in terminal and how should I do that?

To make it more clear, suppose I have this function implemented as "foo", then when I type `foo a` and hit `TAB` in the command line, it should give a list of all files with name containing `a`, then if I continue to type `b` (now the command becomes `foo ab`), then the file list automatically (without need to hit anything else) gets updated to those containing `ab`, and so forth.

Comment: How to get real-time updates of the results?

Comment: @muru Thanks, but that is not what I am asking.  I mean the results need to be updated every time I press down a new key.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? What's the intended use case?

Comment: @muru I added a description, if you could take a look.

Comment: You could try to use a shell called `fish`. It does some auto-completion magic, however it may be not what you want.

Comment: @Helio Thanks, is it similar to `zsh`?

Comment: @username123: Yes, it's similar to `zsh`. However (as far as I know) it does some autocompletion on the user input. As I'm not a Windows user, I can't know if that is what you want.

Comment: @username123: Please check this asciinema recorded in `fish` by me: https://asciinema.org/a/det1crzgnph8m9fwklq50pwqq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This Unix & Linux post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209892/70524) describes what you want:

> ... I've come across a great, universal tool:
>   [command-line fuzzy finder](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf).
>
> It primarily allows you to “fuzzy-find” files (check the rich gif
>   animation by the link above), but it also allows to feed arbitrary
>   text data to it and filter this data. So, the shortcuts idea is
>   simple: all we need is to maintain a file with paths (which are
>   shortcuts), and fuzzy-filter this file. Here's how it looks: we type
>   `cdg` command (from “cd global”, if you like), get a list of our
>   bookmarks, pick the needed one in just a few keystrokes, and press
>   Enter. Working directory is changed to the picked item:
>
> [image: cdg]
>
> It is extremely fast and convenient: usually I just type 3-4 letters
>   of the needed item, and all others are already filtered out.

---

It may not be what you're looking for, but the Vim editor with [the CtrlP plugin](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) can be used for this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

You'll need to install one of `vim`, `vim-nox`, `vim-gnome`, `vim-gtk` or `vim-athena` for this to work. Installation instructions for CtrlP are provided in [its website](http://kien.github.io/ctrlp.vim/#installation):

> 1. Clone the plugin into a separate directory:
>
>    ```
>    $ cd ~/.vim
>    $ git clone https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim.git bundle/ctrlp.vim
>    ```
> 2. Add to your ~/.vimrc:
>
>    ```
>    set runtimepath^=~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim
>    ```
> 3. Run at Vim's command line:
>
>    ```
>    :helptags ~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim/doc
>    ```
> 4. Restart Vim and check `:help ctrlp.txt` for usage instructions and configuration details.

If you have never used Vim before, it can be a bit intimidating. Run `vimtutor` to get an idea of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own completion scripts for your shell.

For example, `bash` uses simple shell scripts / functions for completion. Install `bash-completions` if you haven't already and take a look at `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions` for some examples.

In your script you could simply call `locate` to get a list of matches and return them.